# comparar dos filas de diferentes tablas y obtener los registros iguales MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos  tablas  con los mismos campos pero cada usuario inserta diferentes registros (existe un rango de 78 posibles registros que pueden insertar cada usuario en su tabla) lo que deseo poder hacer es obtener en que campos son similares los registros y en cuales no son  (ya que existe la posibilidad de que sean similares o no sean similares los registros insertados en las tablas de los 2 usuarios)

quiero obtener una fila que muestra en que campos son iguales los registros de las dos tablas de los dos usuarios. cuando son iguales mostrar los registros iguales y cuando no son mostrar un "NULL".

Comment: no uses mayúsculas, que suele verse mal entre la comunidad, también deberías agregar tu query para poder ayudarte, o al menos la estructura de tu base de datos.

Comment: Por favor agrega la estructura de la tablas utilizadas, algo de los datos y un query lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar. Ya que por lo que planteas tu problema se soluciona mediante un INNER JOIN entre las dos tablas comparando todos sus campos en el ON. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Las dos tablas tienen los mismos campos?

Comment: gracias por las respuestas podrias poner un ejemplo INNER JOIN con ON . si los campos son iguales

Comment: Deberías de aportar más información, ademas por similares te refieres a que sean iguales o que coincidan en algunos caracteres ?¿

Answer (score 1):

TablaA (Col1, Col2)
TablaB (Col1, Col2)

```
SELECT * FROM TablaA as A
INNER JOIN TablaB as B
    ON (A.Col1 = B.Col1 and A.Col2 = B.Col2)
```

En la sentencia, puedes ver que comparo la columna1 de la Tabla A con la columna 1 de la Tabla B, lo mismo con la otra columna. Si ejecutas el query se reflejaran los **UNICOS** registros que coincidan en sus columnas respectivas con la otra tabla. Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: El inner no te traera los null

Comment: En caso de necesitar los NULLS, utilizar FULL OUTER JOIN. Saludos.

Comment: guauu amigo parece que es esta la solución que busco, es totalmente lógica, pero ahora ame surgió un problema inesperado intento mostrar el array que obtengo con php y no puedo tal ves tu entiende porque es como  que el result de este SELECT no sale en un formato tipico disculpa la ignorancia.

Comment: hago lo comun en bulce while y mysqli_fetch_assoc o mysqli_fetch_array y nada.

Comment: Primero cambia el inner join por full outer join, luego ejecutalo directamente en sql y mira si tienes resultados, de ser asi continuamos con tu php.

Comment: no funciona... gracias por intentar ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo para que 2 tablas con los mismos campos, quizas podrias hacer en una misma tabla agregar un campo que los diferencie, ej: tipo de movimiento, tipo de operacion etc.

personalmente tener 2 tablas con los mismos datos no es muy buena practica.

podrias enviar tus tablas y ver como poder relacionarlas.

saludos